# comparing two tables based on mutliple columns in any order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, insert-update

I was hoping to get some help with my SQL Server script.

Basically, I have the following requirement:
In the database we have a table called Space. A Space has a length and a width.
We need to upload data from excel sheets we receive. So I upload it into a table and this table also have a length and width.

Now, I need to get the Oid from Space (Oid, Length, Width) into the #spaceTmp table (NULL, Length, Width) but the problem is that length and width can be matched in any order.

Ex:
Space table has the following:
(1, 5, 7)

#spaceTmp has the following:
(NULL, 5, 7)
(NULL, 7, 5)
(NULL, 4, 3)
(NULL, 3, 4)

I need #spaceTmp to have:
(1, 5, 7)
(1, 7, 5)
(2, 4, 3)
(2, 3, 4)

Any advice will be appreciated.

P.S. for simplicity I'm not using GUIDs but integers for Oid column

Comment: Where are you getting the value 2 for the rows `(2, 4, 3) (2, 3, 4)`?

Comment: Sorry, normally I would need to create NEWID() for any space that doesnt already exist, but for simplicity suppose NEWID() will generate a unique integer for this table or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
 -- Setup Script
SELECT NEWID() OID, 5 Width, 7 Length
    INTO #Space



SELECT NEWID() OID, 5 Width, 7 Length
    INTO #SpaceTemp

INSERT INTO #SpaceTemp
SELECT NULL OID, 5 Width, 7 Length

INSERT INTO #SpaceTemp
SELECT NULL OID, 7 Width, 5 Length


INSERT INTO #SpaceTemp
SELECT NULL OID, 4 Width, 3 Length

INSERT INTO #SpaceTemp
SELECT NULL OID, 3 Width, 4 Length

UPDATE #SpaceTemp SET OId = NULL;
*/
UPDATE a
        SET a.OId = COALESCE(b.OId, NEWID())
  FROM #SpaceTemp a LEFT JOIN #Space b
        ON (a.Width = b.Width AND a.Length = b.Length)
        OR (a.Width = b.Length AND a.Length = b.Width)




SELECT * FROM #SpaceTemp
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE #spaceTemp SET Old = ID
FROM Space 
WHERE (Space.Width = #spaceTemp.Width AND Space.Length = #spaceTemp.Length)
OR (Space.Width = #spaceTemp.Length AND Space.Length = #spaceTemp.Width)
```